# Process finished with exit code -1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

После выполнения программы в IntelliJ IDEA в консоли появляется "***Process finished with exit code -1***". Вроде бы должно возвращать: "***Process finished with exit code 0***". Это нормально или что-то не так?

P.S. Программа работает стабильно.

Comment: Программа завершила свое исполнение с ожидаемым результатом "ожидает рестарта"

Comment: А где это написано? Можете дать ссылку?

Comment: О чем вопрос? Если *любая* программа приводит к такому результату, то нужно указать какие действия приводят к ошибке. Если ошибка возникает в конкретной программе, то нужно максимально упростить код и привести его.

Comment: не удалось запустить клиент HCS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что-то пошло не так, общие правило для exit code:

1) код ошибки 0 - программа завершилась успешно,

2) код ошибки >0 - программа завершилась неуспешно, но по ожидаемой причине (пользователь запустил программу с неверными аргументами, она не смогла найти файл конфигурации или подключится к базе данных)

3) код ошибки <0 - программа завершилась неуспешно по не ожидаемой причине (кончилась память, ее убила ОС и т.п.)

По всей вероятности, программа в момент выхода сталкивалась с какими-то системными ошибками (Возникает out of memory error, системная ошибка удаления временных файлов и т.п.). Все-таки лучше посмотреть почему так происходит, возможно она не удаляет за собой временные файлы или начнет падает еще раньше.